# How to SUM multiple DECODE values?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, decode

I have the following decodes in my SELECT case:

```
DECODE (table_name, 'RECHNUNG', SUM(beleg_betrag_offen) ) as re_be_of,
DECODE (table_name, 'GUTSCHRIFT', SUM(beleg_betrag_offen) ) as gs_be_of,
DECODE (table_name, 'ZAHLUNG', SUM(beleg_betrag_offen) ) as za_be_of
```

I want to add up those 3 values (every DECODE has always some results) but I can't. When I write a simple

```
re_be_of + gs_be_of + za_be_of
```

I don't even see any result. Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Comment: You are trying to use aliases in a SELECT expression which is not possible. You need to write the complete expressions, or wrap the first query as a subquery and do the sum in the outer query

Comment: *"I don't even see any result."* . You mean you are seeing the result of that expression as `NULL`?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to show us some sample data and at least one complete query.

Comment: @KaushikNayak yes, sorry.

Comment: Some sample results:

re_be_of = 284985.39
gs_be_of = -19827.87
za_be_of = -4016.52

All I want is to add up those 3 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, should have probably been vice versa: `SUM(DECODE)`, not `DECODE(SUM)`, e.g.

```
with temp as
  (select sum(decode(table_name, 'RECHNUNG'  , beleg_betrag_offen)) as re_be_of,
          sum(decode(table_name, 'GUTSCHRIFT', beleg_betrag_offen)) as gs_be_of,
          sum(decode(table_name, 'ZAHLUNG'   , beleg_betrag_offen)) as za_be_of
   from your_table
  )
select re_be_of,
       gs_be_of,
       za_be_of,
       --
       re_be_of + gs_be_of + za_be_of total
from temp
```

`NVL` function might need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply write:

```
select sum(case when table_name = 'RECHNUNG' then beleg_betrag_offen
           end) as re_be_of,
       sum(case when table_name = 'GUTSCHRIFT' then beleg_betrag_offen
           end) as gs_be_of,
       sum(case when table_name = 'ZAHLUNG' then beleg_betrag_offen
           end) as za_be_of,
       sum(beleg_betrag_offen) as total
from your_table
where table_name in ('RECHNUNG', 'GUTSCHRIFT', 'ZAHLUNG');
```

In addition to using *standard* `CASE` syntax (rather than bespoke and outdated `decode`), this will still provide the sum if any of the `table_name`s are missing in the data.

Oracle has a good optimizer, but filtering *before* aggregation may improve performance.